# How to update running records in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here in below table i want to update the second row opening with first row closing and so on.
Closing column is calculated as (opening + Total)

```
  ID    opening  Total      Closing
  ---   --------  ------------  -------------
   1    0   3015591.25  3015591.25
   2    0   2146798.4   NULL
   3    0   3015591.25  NULL
   4    0   2146798.4   NULL
   5    0   3015591.25  NULL
   6    0   2146798.4   NULL
   7    0   3015591.25  NULL
   8    0   2146798.4   NULL
```

And the **Output**  should be as:

```
       ID    opening      Total     Closing
       ---   --------   ------------  -------------
        1   0           3015591.25  3015591.25
        2   3015591.25  2146798.4   5162389.65
        3   5162389.65  3015591.25  8177981.25
        4   8177980.9   2146798.4   10324779.4
        5   10324779.3  3015591.25  13340370.25
        6   13340370.55 2146798.4   15487168.4
        7   15487168.95 3015591.25  18502759.25
        8   18502760.2  2146798.4   20649557.4
```

any solution on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An answer involving `WHILE` loop.

```
--Simulated your table
DECLARE @tbl TABLE 
(
    ID INT,
    opening FLOAT, 
    Total FLOAT,
    Closing FLOAT
)

--Testing values
INSERT INTO @tbl(ID, opening , Total ,Closing) VALUES(1,0,3015591.25,3015591.25)
INSERT INTO @tbl(ID, opening , Total ,Closing) VALUES(2,0,2146798.4,NULL)
INSERT INTO @tbl(ID, opening , Total ,Closing) VALUES(3,0,3015591.25,NULL)
INSERT INTO @tbl(ID, opening , Total ,Closing) VALUES(4,0,2146798.4,NULL)
INSERT INTO @tbl(ID, opening , Total ,Closing) VALUES(5,0,3015591.25,NULL)
INSERT INTO @tbl(ID, opening , Total ,Closing) VALUES(6,0,2146798.4,NULL)
INSERT INTO @tbl(ID, opening , Total ,Closing) VALUES(7,0,3015591.25,NULL)
INSERT INTO @tbl(ID, opening , Total ,Closing) VALUES(8,0,2146798.4,NULL)

--Solution starts from here
DECLARE @StartCount INT, @TotalCount INT, @OPENING FLOAT,@CLOSING FLOAT

SELECT @TotalCount = MAX(ID) FROM @tbl;
SET @StartCount = 2;

WHILE(@StartCount <= @TotalCount)
BEGIN
    SELECT @OPENING = ISNULL(Closing, 0) FROM @tbl WHERE ID = @StartCount - 1
    SELECT @CLOSING = (@OPENING + Total) FROM @tbl WHERE ID = @StartCount

    UPDATE @tbl
    SET opening = @OPENING,
    Closing = @CLOSING
    WHERE ID = @StartCount

    SELECT @StartCount = @StartCount + 1
END

SELECT * FROM @tbl
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

You can use this query which is based on the fact that your closing value is the sum of totals from all previous rows (current row included) and opening value is the same not including the current row.

```
update table1
set
    Opening = isnull((select sum(total) from table1 t where t.ID < table1.ID), 0),
    Closing = (select sum(total) from table1 t where t.ID <= table1.ID)
```

Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a6a0b7/2) to show that it works.

As this solution recalculates all rows, getting the totals from the beginning, this is more suited to smaller number of records.

Comment: Opening column should be based on Closing value of top row.

Comment: @user1069940 I added a SQL Fiddle to show how it works.

Comment: I don't have SQL Server 2005 around but this doesn't use anything special that wouldn't be available in SQL Server 2005.

Comment: @Szymon Is the order of execution guaranteed here? The fiddle won't open right now.

Comment: @dean There's no order of execution in here, as each row is recalculated from the start (based on the order of ID's).

Comment: it is showing an Error : Must declare the scalar variable "@table".for update @table set ...

Comment: @Szymon Ah, it works now. Execution time will rise exponentially with number of rows, don't you think?

Comment: @Szymon how do i used this script on temporary table declared as "@table" .

Comment: @dean True, it won't perform well in case of big tables. I added a note about it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select id, sum(total) over(order by id)-total as opening, total, sum(total) over(order by id) as closing
from #t
```

Comment: not executing.. showing error : Incorrect syntax near 'order'

Comment: You're using an older version of SQL Server. Pls tag your question with the version tag if you're not using the current mainstream version (which is 2012 now).

Comment: using sql server 2005

Comment: For this kind of select in 2005 you'd be better off using a cursor